# Any design practice of a monolith application development for easy transforming to microservices?

Tags: microservices

To develop a new application for a new business, we are debating whether we shall go for a monolith application or microservices system right now as we don't know how the business will develop in the future. We incline to build a monolith application to start. Any design and development practices of building a monolith application are easy for transforming a monolith application to microservices later?

In terms of technical stack, we are going to use Spring for the back end and Vue for the front end. They can be used for building either a monolith web/mobile application or microservices.

Comment: I would highly suggest you to check domain driven design and understand the concept of bounded context. Try to create as isolated as possible modules  for your bounded contexts. Especially on your database side.Which I always experience as the most tricky part for monolith to microservice migration. Later on you should just create microservices for each bounded context in an ideal world. I am pretty sure it won't happen that easy but at least it saves you a lot of time and reduce the pain.

Comment: That is a quite valid point. One certainly needs to have bounded context in mind when s/he designs domain objects in a monolith application that may migrate to microservices in the future. In microservices, the event-driven design also is used.